# Why is hasId() only returning one of the ids in a list?

Tags: gremlin

I'm using javascript gremlin to get results based on a list of ids:

```
await g
    .addV("test")
    .property(id, "1")
    .addV("test")
    .property(id, "2")
    .next();

const result = await g
    .V()
    .hasId("1","2")
    .next()
```

`result` only contains id 1:
`{"value":{"id":"1","label":"test"},"done":false}`

If I hop on the console, I get the expected result.

```
g.V().hasId("1","2")
==>v[1]
==>v[2]
```

Why is there a discrepancy between these results?

The JS is running in AWS Lambda on Node 10.x.

gremlin: 3.4.2

GraphSON v2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This discrepancy you see is a result of the way the Gremlin Console work whenever the console encounters an `Iterator` it automatically iterates thru all the answers.
While in JS you must use the `Iterator` commands.

When using `Iterator.next()` the result will be the next value in the Iterator.
If you want to get all the values I would use `toList`

```
const result = await g
    .V()
    .hasId("1","2")
    .toList()
```